# select image from existing folder without programming

Tags: media

I uploaded a folder of images to my drupal7 server using WinSCP. I know the path name to these folders as shown below.
[image: WinSCP view of my drupal server files]

I have a field image0 defined for a image for each node.
[image]

The only option I have for defining what image is assigned to the field is to upload a new file from my computer. I don't see any way to select an existing file I already have on my server. The way I would like to do this is to display a list of files for a ceratin path on my server, like File Explorer on Windows. How do I point the field to the path sites/default/files/images/plants/Plant001/photo01.jpg?
[image]

Comment: Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) and try to write this one again. I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking, and if I do, then it seems it lacks any kind of own research.

Answer (score 0):

There is a community module for this purpose which can be paired with a WYSIWYG. It's called [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce). Alternately, you can look at the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module in Drupal 7 which can help accomplish a similar thing.

*P.S. Have to agree with the commenter. I think you might have answered this searching for "File management Drupal". :) Hint: https://www.drupal.org/node/265416*